# Exporting the index values as a list

Tags: python

I have two lists that look like this:

```
speakers = ['S0\n', 'S0\n', 'S0\n', 'S1\n']
breaks = [0.86, 10.31, 22.43, 5.83]
```

My end goal is to sort them according to the time values, so I get these two lists:

```
speakers = ['S0\n', 'S1\n', 'S0\n', 'S0\n']
breaks = [0.86, 5.83, 10.31, 22.43]
```

Therefore I try to do this:

```
#create a dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(breaks, speakers)
df.columns = ['breaks']
df = df.sort(['breaks'], ascending=[1])
```

Now this gives me the dataframe with the ranking I am looking for. However I can destill one list like this:

```
breaks = df['breaks'].tolist()
```

But I cant find a way to export the index values as a list? Any thoughts on how I can do this? Or a better approach for solving my problem?

What

Answer (score 2):

There an attempt without pandas,

```
breaks,speakers = map(list,zip(*sorted(zip(breaks,speakers))))
```

**Execution**,

```
speakers = ['S0\n', 'S0\n', 'S0\n', 'S1\n']
breaks = [0.86, 10.31, 22.43, 5.83]
breaks,speakers = map(list,zip(*sorted(zip(breaks,speakers))))
```

**Result**

```
In [4]: speakers
Out[4]: ['S0\n', 'S1\n', 'S0\n', 'S0\n']

In [5]: breaks
Out[5]: [0.86, 5.83, 10.31, 22.43]
```

**With `pandas`**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['speakers'] = speakers
df['breaks'] = breaks
df = df.sort(['breaks'], ascending=[1])
speakers = df['speakers'].tolist()
breaks = df['breaks'].tolist()
```

**Result**

```
print speakers,breaks
['S0\n', 'S1\n', 'S0\n', 'S0\n'] [0.86, 5.83, 10.31, 22.43]
```

Comment: beat me by 7 seconds :(

Answer (score 1):

how about a one liner but not using pandas?

```
zip(*sorted(zip(speakers, breaks), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

will try to come up with a pandas one too

Answer (score 1):

Zip them, sort them, then unzip them. See the [zip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> breaks2, speakers2 = zip(*sorted(zip(breaks, speakers)))
>>> breaks2
(0.86, 5.83, 10.31, 22.43)
>>> speakers2
('S0\n', 'S1\n', 'S0\n', 'S0\n')
```

Edit: Wow, three near identical, near simultaneous answers. The difference between this and the other two is that they zip `(speakers, breaks)` and then sort by the second element in the tuples, whereas this zips by `(breaks, speakers)` and uses the default sort, which would sort by the first element in the tuple (`breaks`) and then the second (`speakers`) if there are two identical `breaks` values.